# Check if ModPagespeed is allowed and enabled for the current domain via php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

i'm trying to figure out how to check if [ModPagespeed](http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/) is enabled and allowed on the current domain via PHP. I've written the following code, but I'm not fully satisfied of this solution. It works, but it's a crock.

Excerpt from .htaccess (serving different domains) with [Pagespeed filters](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/config_filters):

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed On
  ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough
  ...
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
  ...
</IfModule>
```

Excerpt from pagespeedtest.html:

```
...
<head>
...
  <!-- If combine_css filter is active, the following code should be combined -->
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("/style1.css");</style>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("/style2.css");</style>
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("/style3.css");</style>
...
</head>
```

Check if Pagespeed is enabled or allowed by this PHP code:

```
        $psturl = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/pagespeedtest.html';
        $pagespeed_is_active = TRUE;
        $pstheaders = get_headers($psturl, 1);
        if ($pstheaders['Content-Length'] == 960) {
          $pagespeed_is_active = FALSE;
        }
```

I get the Content-Length header using the PHP 5 function [get_headers($url)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php). I know the original file is 960 bytes long so I suppose that if no optimization is performed the Content-Length should be the same when served to the client.

Are there any alternatives to this approach? I don't like the supplemental HTTP request I perform on pagespeedtest.html and that solution strongly relies on PageSpeed configuration: if <kbd>combine_css</kbd> filter will be disabled, I will got <kbd>$pagespeed_is_active == FALSE</kbd> even when ModPagespeed is <kbd>On</kbd> and allowed.

An alternative solution must be validated through different domains, since I can disallow some domains in this very same .htaccess. Thank you.

Comment: Configure your server, use mod_info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_info.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the `Content-Length`, you can instead look for the `X-Mod-Pagespeed` header, which will give you the answer you're looking for as long as "ModPageSpeed on" directive is there for the domain.

Other then that, I don't think there is any way for you to check if PageSpeed is enabled from within the request. The whole point of PageSpeed is that it runs as an output filter: you generate your page, PageSpeed picks it up and does the optimization and rewriting.

Comment: Thank you very much igrigorik! I've upgraded mod-pagespeed-beta package to 0.10.22.4 (from a 0.10.21.x) and now I can simply check if pagespeed is active declaring the $pagespeed_is_active variable like this: `$pagespeed_is_active = isset($pstheaders['X-Mod-Pagespeed']);`. If ModPagespeed is disallowed for the request via something like `ModPagespeedDisallow http://example.com/pagespeedtest.html`, then $pagespeed_is_active will be FALSE.